# get checkbox state from controller

Tags: javascript, grails, checkbox, controller

my Grails project I have a checkbox. I want to call a `remoteFunction` in `onCheck()` method of the checkbox, like the following:

```
if(checkbox.isChecked)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do some other thing
}
```

The fact is that I don't know how to get the state of the checkbox in controller, after its check / uncheck. Is it needed to use some javascript code?
Any suggestion?

EDIT:
this is the checkbox

```
<g:checkBox name="hasStampDuty" value="${receiptInstance?.hasStampDuty}"
            onclick="${remoteFunction(
                    controller: 'Receipt',
                    action: 'addStampDuty',
                    params: '\'id=\' + this.id+\'ischecked=\'+this.checked',
                    onSuccess: 'updateTotalAmount(\'totalAmount\', data, \'00000\')')}"
/>
```

where addStampDuty is as follows:

```
def addStampDuty(Long id, boolean ischecked)
{
    //add stamp duty value
    def receiptInstance = Receipt.get(id)
    if(ischecked != null)
    {
        if(ischecked) {
                  //do something
        }
        else {
              //do some other
        }

    }

}
```

But `id` is always null...

Comment: The state of a checkbox in a controller is if the element exits with a value or not in the params. For example, if you have an element called 'something' and it's checked when the form is sent to your controller params.something will have a value. If it's not checked then params.something won't have a value.

Comment: the fact is that I need to check the checkbox before the sumbit, so the params has not the params.something

Comment: Then you may want to rephrase your question since you said "get the current state of the checkbox in controller".

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the state of the checkbox is passed to the action in parameters. As noted in the comments above, the presence or not of a parameter with the form "${fieldName}.selected" indicates whether the checkbox is selected (checked) or not. I agree that it is a little awkward. However if you muck with the parameters directly, then you may have messed up that contract.

You can put the following code at the start of your action to see exactly what it is passed in params:

```
   log.info("Executing \"blah\" action.")
   params.each { log.info("Param ${it.key} = {$it.value}") }
```

As a side note, if you want to do this on all actions, then create a filter (see Grails filters) and cross cut as you see fit.

Finally, I believe that the Grails AJAX wrapper tags have been deprecated and you should probably avoid their use. Just post the form using the jquery (or whatever you fancy) AJAX client support and let the form fields populate the params in the normal Grails conventions. You should read the